# How can all.js be created manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the function for caching multiple javascript files into one:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all, :cache => true %>
```

The way I understand it this creates the all.js file the first time a HTML file using it is generated.

But if the app is configured to use an asset host on a seperate server that does not deliver HTML the file will not be created. Is there a way to generate all.js manually on deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure your deploy task in order to compress and create the file.
If you use Capistrano, [you can add a callbac](http://involution.com/2009/06/18/using-yuicompressor-with-capistrano-and-rails-2-3-on-combined-javascript-and-css/)k to be executed on deploy.

Otherwise, the are a couple of alternatives that offers also a more efficient solution. The standard Rails strategy only merges all files into a single one. But you can gain additional benefit by compressing and minifying the final result. For more information you can read the [GitHub asset deployment strategy](http://github.com/blog/551-optimizing-asset-bundling-and-serving-with-rails) or the [Jammit documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/).

Comment: After reading up on the different sources I was able to create a capistrano task that creates an identical file to the on Rails creates. Run after "deploy:update_code"    --- run "cd #{release_path}/public/javascripts && sed -s '$G' $(find . -name '*.js' ! -name all* | sort -r) | sed '$d' > all.js && gtouch all.js -r $(gls -t1 --hide=all* | head -n1)"

Answer (score 0):

A great project for javascript concatenation is sprockets, which can be found here: http://getsprockets.org/

It's really easy to setup and integrate with capistrano.  Might be worth a look.